# Geolocation in Apex oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, geolocation, oracle-apex

I have a code JS, it returns the exact coordinates of my location,longitude and latitude. I want this information to automatically fall into P1_GEO when filling out the form. I tried to connect it to dynamic action but nothing worked.
There may be a problem with the code

```
window.onload = function() {

    var startPos;
    var geoSuccess = function(position) {
        startPos = position;
     console.log(startPos.coords.latitude);
     console.log(startPos.coords.longitude); 
     alert(startPos);
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with the following format

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      function setPosition(position) {
        console.log( position.coords.latitude);
        console.log( position.coords.longitude);
      }
);
```

Where you should be able to replace console.log with something like

```
$s('P1_GEO',  position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
```

Comment: I understand correctly, I am engaging in dynamic action to execute java code "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      function setPosition(position) {
        $s('P1_GEO',  position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
      }
);"

Comment: my return "A Geolocation request can only be fulfilled in a secure context."

Comment: On page load is sufficient to run this JavaScript. 
Sounds like you have a new error regarding your non-usage of SSL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the APEX Store Location plug-in from [APEX world](https://apex.world):

https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:14435124796778::::P710_PLG_ID:NL.DETORA.APEX.STORELOCATION

You can find the plug-in in your browser by:
- navigating to APEX World
- choose Plug-ins in Plug-ins menu
- enter 'location' in the search item
- press Enter
- Chose the Store location plug-in

Comment: Please provide a descriptive solution to the question as link may get redirect/expired in future.